# HTML Email - Image with <a> tag inverts colour on click - Outlook

Tags: image, outlook, click, anchor, html-email

Outlook 2010 - Weird colour invert upon click

Style sheet:

```
<style>
img {outline:none; text-decoration:none;}
a img {border:none;}
.image_fix {display:block;}
</style>
```

Code in table:

```
<td height="180" valign="bottom">
<a href="www.URL.com"><img align="right" class="image_fix" src="http://" alt="" title=""></a>
</td>
```

It happens to all but one image which is approx 4x bigger with the same code:

```
<td valign="top" height="365" rowspan="2" colspan="2"><a href="www.URL.com"><img class="image_fix" src="http://www.URL.com" alt="" title=""></a></td>
```

Comment: Things I have tried:
- removing the <a> tag and putting href inside the <img> tag with the same effect. 
- replacing the image that works with an image that doesn't. Just inverts the new image.
- taken the <a> and href tag oot which disables the colour inversion on click which leads me to believe its a format that outlook is putting on image with links.

Comment: So you are using an image as a link, correct? And when pressed, the colors invert on the image, but should revert back on mouse_up action. Is that the case?

Comment: Hi @artcase , apologies for the late reply. yes when you release mouse click it reverts to normal

Comment: I've  not found a method to "trick" Outlook 2010 to change it's default link (onClick) color, or "visited" color palette for links. Images seem okay because you can remove any border properties and they stick in the cascade. I think the original concept behind inverting an image color was to make certain the user knows they clicked on a link. Couldn't find it in Google search though. As to why it isn't happening on one image, I'd double check to make certain that a closing " or something like that was missed, rendering the link technically invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, haven't seen this before. You might want to keep from using rowspan and colspan though because a lot of e-mail clients have difficulties with these.

What behavior do you get when you just insert an anchor without the image? Do you get the same behavior from a text-only link?

In the past I've had some problems using png-files in different clients. What format are you using?

Comment: Hi @BraMKJ , sorry for the late response! Unfortunately I never got round to making this work. 

I'm using jpegs for the images and text links are working appropriately.